# how to use a button to select data from pickerview (swift4)

Tags: ios, select, button, swift4, picker

I want to use a button to select the data from my picker view. Currently my code uses the button to dismiss the picker view but the button does not select anything from the picker view. The only way something is selected is if a scroll using the picker view. How can I use my button as the only way to submit the data for the picker view?

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    for textFieldObject in theScoreRound
    {
        textFieldObject.inputView = picker

        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

        items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) )
        items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction)) )
        items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) )

        toolbar.items = items


        let fs = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let db = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction))
        toolbar.setItems([fs,db],animated: false)
        textFieldObject.inputAccessoryView = toolbar



    }}
   @objc func doneAction(){

    view.endEditing(true)

}
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numberX.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numberX[row]
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    for textField in theScoreRound {
        if textField.isEditing {
            textField.text = numberX[row]

        }
    }

    self.view.endEditing(false)
}

@IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {
    var total = 0
    for view in theScoreRound {
        if let text = view.text, let num = Int(text) {
            total += num

        }
    }
    fighterAScore.text = String(total)

}
```

Comment: You need to use the  `self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: <#T##Int#>)` method to get the selected row in the component and using your UIPickerDataSource you can get the value

Comment: in what function do I put that in?

Comment: In you UIButton Action, I can provide some example if you want

Comment: If you could that would be great? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UIPickerView` `selectedRow(inComponent: <#T##Int#>)` method where you pass the component number in this case 0 because in your `UIPickerDataSource` you are returning 1 in the `numberOfComponents` method

**Example Code**

```
@IBAction func pickerDataAction(_ sender: Any) {
   let selectedRow = self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
   let desiredValue = numberX[selectedRow]
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I added my button of what I am using to select my score of the picker view. I added your code but it does not work. I am using a outlet collection, if that clears any confusion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you update your code with what you have now? @SamBurns

Comment: I added the button at the very end of my current code. I edited my question at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Let me understand well your question, in your last piece of code what are you trying to do and where is the value from the UIPicker involved, can you explain me a little more about this? @SamBurns

Comment: My piece of edited code takes the collection of textfields and when a score is added it adds it to a single textfield. Basically rounds and then a tallying final score.